# Shaping data for a resolver

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, mongoose

Essentially this resolver returns a list of quotes, which can be from different books stored in a mongo db. This is the structure of [the db!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvdfE.png)

```js
    getQuotes: async () => {
      const getQuotes = await booksModel.find({}, "quotes");
      console.log(getQuotes);
      // #1

      for (const element of getQuotes) {
        const test = element.quotes;
        console.log(test)
        // #2

        Object.values(test).forEach((val) => {
          console.log(val);
          // #3
          
          return val;
        });
      }
    },
```

Which returns something very similar to the shape that the data needs to be...

This is console.log #3!

```
{
  book: 1,
  page: 12,
  excerpt: 'asaaaad',
  comment: 'asd',
  _id: 'N_YOT_Gms_fvAqQKL3Y23'
}
{
  book: 1,
  page: 12,
  excerpt: 'sdfsdfsdfsdf',
  comment: 'asd',
  _id: 'QP5iLh3Gj2X8ZcSN7hoPF'
}
{
  book: 2,
  page: 12,
  excerpt: 'asaasdasdaad',
  comment: 'asd',
  _id: '2kdkfgW6MERwGtvbXph9e'
}
```

This is console.log #2!

```
[
  {
    book: 1,
    page: 12,
    excerpt: 'asaaaad',
    comment: 'asd',
    _id: 'N_YOT_Gms_fvAqQKL3Y23'
  },
  {
    book: 1,
    page: 12,
    excerpt: 'sdfsdfsdfsdf',
    comment: 'asd',
    _id: 'QP5iLh3Gj2X8ZcSN7hoPF'
  }
]
[
  {
    book: 2,
    page: 12,
    excerpt: 'asaasdasdaad',
    comment: 'asd',
    _id: '2kdkfgW6MERwGtvbXph9e'
  }
]
```

This is console.log #1!

```
[
  { _id: 'leO68YLuG_mG4KS491Kpz', quotes: [ [Object], [Object] ] },
  { _id: 'ymbUWql0sREAKuaVXZ_KY', quotes: [ [Object] ] }
]
```

Except that I'm stuck within forEach and can't structure this into a pretty array for my graphql resolver. I was wondering how else would anybody approach this to better my perspective? It's been a good year or so since I've picked this up, so don't mind me too much; I did most of the work (ok well I tried) :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want to use `.flatMap`:

```
getQuotes: async () => {
    const quotes = await booksModel.find({}, "quotes");
    return quotes.flatMap((el) => el.quotes);
}
```

```js
const quotes = [{
    _id: 'leO68YLuG_mG4KS491Kpz',
    quotes: [{
        book: 1,
        page: 12,
        excerpt: 'asaaaad',
        comment: 'asd',
        _id: 'N_YOT_Gms_fvAqQKL3Y23'
      }, {
        book: 1,
        page: 12,
        excerpt: 'sdfsdfsdfsdf',
        comment: 'asd',
        _id: 'QP5iLh3Gj2X8ZcSN7hoPF'
      
    }],
  }, {
    _id: 'ymbUWql0sREAKuaVXZ_KY',
    quotes: [{
        book: 2,
        page: 12,
        excerpt: 'asaasdasdaad',
        comment: 'asd',
        _id: '2kdkfgW6MERwGtvbXph9e'
    }]
}];

console.log(quotes.flatMap((el) => el.quotes));
```

And if you're environment doesn't support it (it's a new-ish js feature) just do

```
if (!Array.prototype.flatMap) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'flatMap', {
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: function () {
      return Array.prototype.map.apply(this, arguments).flat(1);
    },
  });
}
```